# Trouble scraping Google trends using Capybara and Poltergeist

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara, screen-scraping, poltergeist

I want to get the top trending queries in a particular category on Google Trends. I could download the CSV for that category but that is not a viable solution because I want to branch into each query and find the trending sub-queries for each.

I am unable to capture the contents of the following table, which contains the top 10 trending queries for a topic. Also for some weird reason taking a screenshot using capybara returns a darkened image.

```
<div id="TOP_QUERIES_0_0table" class="trends-table">
```

Please run the code on the Ruby console to see it working. Capturing elements/screenshot works fine for facebook.com or google.com but doesn't work for trends.

I am guessing this has to do with the table getting generated dynamically on page load but I'm not sure if that should block capybara from capturing the elements already loaded on the page. Any hints would be very valuable.

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'csv'


class PoltergeistCrawler
  include Capybara::DSL

  def initialize
    Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_crawler do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
        :js_errors => false,
        :inspector => false,
        phantomjs_logger: open('/dev/null')
      })
    end
    Capybara.default_wait_time = 3
    Capybara.run_server = false
    Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist_crawler
    page.driver.headers = {
      "DNT" => 1,
      "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
    }
  end

  # handy to peek into what the browser is doing right now
  def screenshot(name="screenshot")
    page.driver.render("public/#{name}.jpg",full: true)
  end

  # find("path") and all("path") work ok for most cases. Sometimes I need more control, like finding hidden fields
  def doc
    Nokogiri.parse(page.body)
  end
end

crawler = PoltergeistCrawler.new
url = "http://www.google.com/trends/explore#cat=0-45&geo=US&date=today%2012-m&cmpt=q"
crawler.visit url

crawler.screenshot

crawler.find(:xpath, "//div[@id='TOP_QUERIES_0_0table']")
```

Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "//div[@id='TOP_QUERIES_0_0table']"
    from /Users/karan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:41:in `block in find'
    from /Users/karan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in`synchronize'
    from /Users/karan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:30:in `find'
    from /Users/karan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:676:in`block (2 levels) in '
    from /Users/karan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
    from (irb):45
    from /Users/karan/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p484/bin/irb:12:in`'

Comment: I turned on js_errors and indeed a javascript error is being thrown. .......Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError: Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError
 from /Users/karan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:275:in `command'

.....How to get around this?

Comment: Turned inspector=> true and did crawler.page.driver.debug

There's this error in the script http://www.google.com/trends/resources/3724719769-alljs-bin__en_us.js

...TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.document_releaseCapture()')

Answer (score 1):

The javascript error was due to the incorrect USER-Agent. Once I changed the User Agent to that of my chrome browser it worked !

"User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"